# how do i make the scroll bar scroll the lines only without scrolling the image

Tags: html, scrollbar, scrollpane

How do I scroll the line only without scrolling the image in the scrollpane?
I'm currently doing it on html, any suggestions please? I've yet to learn jQuery, is there anyway that this can be done with just html coding?
[image]

these are my current coding:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*  bhoechie tab */
div.bhoechie-tab-container{
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  opacity: 0.97;
  filter: alpha(opacity=97);
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a .glyphicon,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a .fa {
  color: #5A55A3;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a:first-child{
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a:last-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active .glyphicon,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active .fa{
  background-color: #5A55A3;
  background-image: #5A55A3;
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #5A55A3;
}

div.bhoechie-tab-content{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* border: 1px solid #eeeeee; */
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

div.bhoechie-tab div.bhoechie-tab-content:not(.active){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="../Documents/Unnamed Site 2/Untitled-4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<div style="height:380px;width:380px;overflow:auto;">
<img src="scroll/src/denso.jpg" alt="Sample picture for scroll box">
<hr COLOR="BLACK" WIDTH="60%" >
<div class="vertical_line"></div>

</div>

<style>


.vertical_line{position: relative; top: 0; left:0;  right:0;}
.vertical_line{position: absolute; top:10px; left:190px; right: 190px; height:360px; width:3px;background:#000; }

</style>



<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hard to say just by seeing image, share the code of both HTML and CSS.

Comment: line is separate element or it comes with image ... confusion . provide code or explain

Comment: @Manjuboyz I just shared it.

Comment: @ihemant360 line is separate element.

Comment: Use position of image to position : fixed.

Comment: set image position =  fixed and line position to absolute and try

Comment: Am not sure its more to ask, could you share your code in fiddle, since its hard for us to check the code, reason scroll never appears!!

Answer (score 0):

If images is not dependent on the line, then instead of using Position:absolute,
you can change that to

```
.image{    

Position:fixed;
}
```

so that it will fit in to the container.

Comment: It's still not working. The image still moves while the vertical line does not move.

Comment: Am not sure its more to ask, could you share your code in fiddle, since its hard for us to check the code, reason scroll never appears!!